# Bootable flash drive meant to boot Windows 7 boots Linux Mint 15

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 15 and I want to switch to Windows 7. I tried to make a bootable SD card, but something is wrong.

I downloaded Windows 7, right-clicked the .iso file -> "make bootable USB stick". A process runs for 20 minutes and returns "your flash drive is now bootable" or something to that effect. I power on -> choose Boot from SD card -> Linux Mint 15 boots.

Why isn't Windows 7 booting?